# Sorting pandas pivot table keeping the multiple indexes match

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to sort a dataframe keeping the match between the indexes?

My df:

```
             budget population
state   fu      
acre    ac1  600    50
        ac2  25     110
bahia   ba1  2300   80
        ba2   1     10
paulo   sp1  1000   100
        sp2  1000   230
```

I would like to get the output below, since index bahia has the grater total budget:

```
             budget population
state   fu      
bahia   ba1  2300   80
        ba2   1     10
paulo   sp1  1000   100
        sp2  1000   230
acre    ac1  600    50
        ac2  25     110
```

But after using sort_values() I get the output below:

```
              budget population
state   fu      
bahia   ba1   2300   80
paulo   sp1   1000   100
        sp2   1000   230
acre    ac1   600    50
        ac2   25     110
bahia   ba2    1     10
```

**I updated the question to give more context**

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? The command `df.sort_values(by="budget", ascending=False)` returns what you want, IIUC.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, what is the expected output?

Comment: @Evan solution should work.

Comment: I updated the question to give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to sort without calculating the total budget. IIUC, this should return what you need, even if some states have a larger total budget than others, but smaller `fu` budgets.

First, we group `budget` by state.
Second, calculate the `max` budget.
Third, sort those values in descending order.
Fourth, take the `index` of this new `Series` of `state` names.
Lastly, `reindex` the appropriate `level` of our original `df` with the new order.

```
new_index = df["budget"]\
    .groupby("state")\
    .max()\
    .sort_values(ascending=False)\
    .index # just return the index

df.reindex(new_index, level=0)
```

Output:

```
           budget  population
state fu                     
bahia ba1    2300          80
      ba2       1          10
paulo sp1    1000         100
      sp2    1000         230
acre  ac1     600          50
      ac2      25         110
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. One of the ways would be to calculate the metric that you want to sort on (total budget), sort the dataframe and then remove the newly created variable.

We will have to reset the indices of the original dataframe inorder to be able to merge properly.

```
#Creating the total budget variable
gp = df.groupby('state')['budget'].sum().reset_index()
gp.columns = ['state','total_budget']

#Merging with the total budget variable
out = df.reset_index().merge(gp, on='state')

#Sorting based on total_budget
out = out.sort_values('total_budget', ascending = False)
out.drop('total_budget',inplace = True, axis = 1)
out = out.set_index(['state','fu'])
```

The final output looks like

```
           budget  population
state fu                     
bahia ba1    2300          80
      ba2       1          10
paulo sp1    1000         100
      sp2    1000         230
acre  ac1     600          50
      ac2      25         110
```

In addition to this, a more compact solution would be

```
out = pd.concat([x[1] for x in sorted(df.reset_index().groupby('state'), key = lambda x : -np.sum(x[1].budget) )]).set_index(['state','fu'])
```

Here too, `out` gives the same output as before.

Comment: Nice! I'm trying to see if there's a way to do this without calculating a total budget...

Comment: I just added a solution that doesnt calculate total_buget. It does the entire computation in just 1 line.